# Season Pass from Origin for a Ubisoft Game

Tags: origin, ubisoft-connect

I have Assassin's Creed III linked to my Uplay account. I want season pass for the game. The season pass in Uplay is bit expensive when compared to Origin. So is it possible to buy the season pass from Origin and activate it in Uplay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Origin provided Key which I used to activate in Uplay.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I vaguely remember activating a couple of games bought from Steam in Uplay and/or Origin.